# How to create a remote mailslot in win32 programming?

Tags: winapi, mailslot

```
hMailslot = CreateMailslot("\\\\.\\Mailslot\\client", 0, MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER, NULL);
```

This is the mailslot that I created for local machine and it works.

How, exactly can I create for a mailslot for a remote machine?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Mailslot Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the "ComputerName" thing:

> More frequently, you would use the following form to write to a
>   mailslot on a specific remote computer:
>
> \\ComputerName\mailslot\[path]\name